# what does "android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable" mean ? How can I solve it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play

I am getting the following in the Play console. I don't know what JavaProxyThrowable means. How can I find out what the error means and fix it?

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: 
  at DiabeticNow.MainActivity+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<OnCreate>b__1 (System.Object <p0>, System.EventArgs <p1>) [0x01744] in <dabfa6ee96644f0a980241e8b5bd1c61>:0
  at Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerImplementor.OnClick (Android.Views.View v) [0x00011] in <794f2773dcf94ef592cfddeec7272681>:0
  at Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_v) [0x0000f] in <794f2773dcf94ef592cfddeec7272681>:0
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:04a4eea7-8182-4d20-9207-17bd8bcbd598 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick (Native Method)
  at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick (View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6261)
  at android.widget.TextView.performClick (TextView.java:11159)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:23748)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a method that Xamarin uses to turn C# exceptions into Java exceptions. There seems to be details of where the problem might be in your C# code:

```
 DiabeticNow.MainActivity+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__1 (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x01744] in :0 
    at Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerImplementor.OnClick (Android.Views.View v) [0x00011] in <794f2773dcf94ef592cfddeec7272681>:0 
    at Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_v) [0x0000f] in ...
```

If you posted the relevant c# code and tagged with C# someone might be able to help.